# Extract all lines from multiline item

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, multiple-values

In our Sharepoint 2010 site, I've created a list with a multi line column. I try to extract all lines from this field but receive only the last entry. This field is used to put comments of users:

[image: Sharepoint comments]

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint-host

$list = $web.Lists["Demo List"]

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.RowLimit = 10

$query.Query = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">4537</Value></Eq></Where><'

$items = $list.GetItems($query)

foreach($item in $items){
    Write-Host "Activity ID : " $item.ID "-" $item["my-multi-line-item"]
  }
```

In this case it returns only the comment of Anne. What is the correct way to get all lines?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried to reproduce your issue on my environment, but everything is working fine. I could get all lines on multiple lines of text fields (both the plain and rich text).

Comment: @AWJ Thanks for reproducing. See updated question. I only get the most recent comment.

Comment: I have used your script on, multiline filed , in all types (Plan and rich). It's working properly. May be its because you are using 2010, actually i have test it on SharePoint 2013

Comment: What is the column type of the comment field? Is it really a multiple lines of text?

Comment: @AWJ The column type is 'multiple lines of text' with append text enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list has versioning turned on. Also the multi line field has "Append only changes" setting enabled. So thats why you are getting only the latest value in the field.

[image]

Try with below code:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint-host

$list = $web.Lists["Demo list"]

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.RowLimit = 10

$query.Query = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">4537</Value></Eq></Where>'

$items = $list.GetItems($query)

foreach($item in $items){

    $VersionData = ''
    foreach($version in $item.Versions)
    {    
            $VersionData+= $version["Comments"]             
    }    
    Write-Host $VersionData
  }
```